# Find a closed formula for Stirling numbers of the first kind

Tags: combinatorics

Find a closed formula for $(,−4)$, for all $n \geq 4$.

Attempt:

$n-1$ cycles of $1$ and $1$ cycle of $5$, $n-2$ cycles of $1$ with $1$ cycle of $4$ and one cycle of $2$, $n-2$ cycles of $1$ and $2$ cycles of $3$, one cycle with three with $2$ cycles of $2$ and $n-3$ cycles of $1$, $n-4$ cycles of $1$ and $4$ cycles of $2$.

$(n-1,0,0,0,1, \ldots), (n-2, 1,0, 1, \ldots), (n-2, 0,2, \ldots), (n-3,2,1,1,0, \ldots), (n-4, 4, 0,0, \ldots)$

How do I make a general formula out of these cycle permutations?

Comment: [Another](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Expansions_for_fixed_k) representation? What are the prerequisites?

Comment: No prereqs, except n >= 4. The problem could be solved in any way